# cypress download: "cypress run" appears to be the same as "cypress open"

Tags: cypress

I'm using the zip file download of Cypress as the server it's running on can't access npm.

I've added the following to the scripts section pf package.json

```
    "cy:cypress": "D:/Cypress/cypress.exe",
    "cy:open": "D:/Cypress/cypress.exe open",
    "cy:run": "D:/Cypress/cypress.exe run",
```

All of them generate the page show in the image below, which I believe is the dashboard.

My understanding is that the third of these runs the tests headlessly.

It's almost like 'open' and 'run' are ignored in the 2nd and 3rd script so in reality thay are all calls to cypress.exe.

- Is this expected behaviour?
- Can the download version of Cypress 'run' tests?
- if so how?

Thanks

[image: What the first 3 scripts generate]

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to execute cypress executable here, which won't work, you have to use cypress command which is installed globally or execute it from your node_modules, so here are the two ways -

1. `npx cypress open`
2. `node_modules\.bin\cypress open`
3. `cypress open` - this will work if you have cypress installed globally and `cypress` command is part of your operating system's environment variables

You can replace the command `open` with `run` preferably if you want to run it in headless mode by using `--headless` option which means it will not open the runner and it will just run the tests in the terminal.

Slightly unrelated, but you can also use `--spec` to specifically run a particular test and `--browser chrome` to run it on a specified browser e.g. chrome in this command

Answer (score 0):

*npx cypress run*
open cmd where you cypress file exist the run the above command it will run headless without UI

Answer (score 0):

You can click select manually and select your project. It will open the cypress project. The details can be found in the video [Direct Download](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#:%7E:text=If%20you%27re%20not%20using,possible%20from%20the%20direct%20download.)